# Remove the deeper jsonb element in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, jsonb

```
[ 
   { 
      "type":"test.added",
      "values":[ 
         { 
            "field":"field1",
            "value":"fieldValue1"
         },
         { 
            "field":"field2",
            "value":"fieldValue2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to remove the 'field1' object pair from the JSON in Postgres.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- `updatedJson -> 0 ->> 'values' - '"field1"'`
- I tried using `#-` to delete the field or element with specified path (for JSON arrays, negative integers count from the end)

Both steps didn't help me. I am new to Postgres. Is there any way like getting the path and deleting it. I am using jsonb. PostgreSQL version: 9.6.

Answer (score 0):

> i tried using the #-

What specifically did you try?

Using #- works for me, specifically `updatedJson #- '{0,values,0}'`

Comment: i dont know the index. how to calculate the index of the particular field. it may in any position @jjanes,